# How to correctly create a block using mainly flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the task of compose such a block. I could make it using  **CSS3** `position relative position absolute.`

> And need to compose this block using **Flexbox**.

What i have got it's in the  bottom.If it's possible try to use it and don't write from scratch.

[image]

```css
.item {
 position: relative;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(41,51,57,.5);
 color: #37454d;
 background: #fff;
}
.item_wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 100%;
}
.item_image {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
    transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
    transition: transform .3s;
    transition: transform .3s,-webkit-transform .3s;
}

.image-area {
 padding: 8px 6px 8px 8px;
 width: 22.25%;
 float: left;
}
.image-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 line-height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.image-wrapper:hover{
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
.image_gallery {
 top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    background: 0;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    border:0;
} 

.flex-column {
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: stretch;
}

.item_details {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 border-right: 1px solid #cdd0d2;
 margin: 8px 0;
 border-bottom: 0;
 float: left;
 padding: 0 8px 0 4px;
}
.item_name {
 margin-bottom: 16px;
 font-size: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
}
.name_copytext {
 color: #005f81;
 margin: 0;
 max-width: calc(100% - 38px);
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
 direction: ltr;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
}


.item_location {
 overflow: hidden;
} 
.details_paragraph {
 padding-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 16px;
 line-height: 1.30;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.item_dynamic-content {
 display: block;
 font-size: 12px;
 padding: 0;
}
.item_deal {
 display: flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 align-items: stretch;
 -webkit-align-items:stretch;
 padding: 8px;
 width: 47%;
}
.item_best-details {
 display: flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 -webkit-flex-direction:column;
 flex-direction: column;
 -webkit-justify-content:space-around;
 justify-content: space-around;
 -webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-grow:2;
 -webkit-flex-grow:2;
 clear: none;
 float: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-order:3;
 order: 3;
}
```

```html
<article class="item">
  <div class="item_wrapper">
    <div class="image-area">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/07/6e/64/52/hyatt-regency-santa-clara.jpg" class="item_image">
        <button type="button" class="image_gallery">
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="item_details">
        <div class="item_name">
          <h3 class="name_copytext" title="Hyatt Regency Santa Clara">Hyatt Regency Santa Clara</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item_location">
          <p class="details_paragraph">Santa Clara, California, USA </p>
        </div>
        <div class="item_review">
          <div class="details_paragraph">
            <em class="rating-number">
              <span class="rating-number_value">Very good</span>
            </em>
            <span class="review_count">(2045 reviews)</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <section class="item_deal">
        <div class="item-link">
          <div class="item_best-details">
            <!-- dozen blocks-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cheapskate/ubj3dzqb/)

Comment: Do you want others to do it for you?

Comment: @JustuseFlex because otherwise i cant post the question

Comment: @MattiaAstorino No!.I need just a little help from experienced  programmer

Comment: But surely that doesn't justify it's presence though. Don't you think there are reasons for such requirements?

Comment: @JustuseFlex yup ur right.I know there are reason for such requirements.But i can't  find the right words to write there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the box model you must follow to do it with flexbox and with a clear structure. Each area is a container.

[image]

```css
.Card,
.Card * {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  margin: 8px;
}

.Card {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 300px;
}


.Picture {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Picture img {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.Desc {
  height: 20px;
}


.Content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ContentHead {
  height: 20px;
}

.ContentDetail {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}


.Details {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.Side {
  flex-basis: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Card">
   <div class="Picture">
     <img src="" alt="">
     <div class="Desc"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="Content">
     <div class="ContentHead"></div>
     <div class="ContentDetail">
       <div class="Details"></div>
       <div class="Side"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here your code. You can improve it avoiding flex where you don't need it.